# Merge [computer-architecture] and [cpu-architecture] tags as [computer-architecture]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

#### Summary

The tags [cpu-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) and [computer-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture) should be merged together under the [computer-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture) tag.

#### Details

I follow the [computer-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture) tag and also some related ones.  Today I noticed [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642902/intel-cpus-instruction-queue-provides-static-branch-prediction) that I thought was interesting, and I was surprised that it was not tagged as [computer-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture).  That was when I found out there is another tag, [cpu-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) (which I now follow as well).

The [cpu-architecture tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cpu-architecture/info) is described as:

> The hardware microarchitecture (x86, x86_64, ARM, ...) of a CPU or
>   microcontroller.
>
> Use this tag for questions regarding features or bugs in relation to
>   only specific CPU architectures.
>
> Don't use this question if you have no reason to believe your issue is
>   related to the CPU architecture.

While the [computer-architecture tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/computer-architecture/info) is described as:

> Computer architecture deals with how computing system (CPUs, GPUs,
>   DSPs and other accelerators, embedded systems, etc..) are designed and
>   organized, and how to interact with them by the code running on them.
>
> This includes both the external documented behavior that the machine
>   is required to uphold, system level design, instruction set (ISA),
>   interactions with operating systems, vM layers or drivers, memory
>   organization and accessing behavior, and so on. It also encompasses
>   the internal micro-architecture, defining how different machines
>   perform the code execution internally through various HW
>   optimizations.

In my opinion these tags will apply to the same set of questions.  However, the reason that I am asking this question on meta rather than just suggesting a synonym is that there is already a suggestion for `computer-architecture` to be a synonym of `cpu-architecture`.  The synonym suggestion currently has 2 votes.

This prevents me from suggesting that `computer-architecture` be the main tag.  However, **computer architecture** is the more commonly used name for this field as can be seen by looking at things like [course titles](https://www.coursera.org/course/comparch), [conference titles](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/calcm/isca2015/), [textbook titles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012383872X), etc.

In addition the `computer-architecture` tag currently has more questions and follower than `cpu-architecture`.  So I think `computer-architecture` should be the main tag and `cpu-architecture` listed as a synonym.

Finally it could be argued that there are subtle differences between the two tags and that they should not be merged.  But in my opinion the `cpu-architecture` tag is so broad that it effectively completely overlaps with `computer-architecture`.  It doesn't narrow the scope in any way and it's completely arbitrary which tag is picked.  If the tag were for a specific architecture (x86, MIPS, etc.) then obviously it should not be merged.  And in fact if someone wants to ask a question that is for a specific architecture they should use a tag for a specific architecture.  Otherwise the tag `cpu-architecture` covers the same topics as `computer-architecture`.

Answer (score 6):

The two are completely different.  CPU-architecture would be questions about instruction set, page tables, branch prediction, etc.  Computer-architecture would be about busses, co processing with the GPU, peripherals, etc.  The two are not synonyms.  Computer architecture is at a much higher level in the abstraction.  You can make a case for either or both being too broad, but they aren't the same.

Comment: `CPU-architecture would be questions about instruction set, page tables, branch prediction, etc.` all of which are topics covered in the textbook `Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach`.  Of course we are free to disagree, but I think "completely different" is a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: I don't think it is. At best your argument would be that c doesn't deserve a tag because languages has one

Comment: I'll grant that if you want to be pedantic there is a difference between computer architecture and CPU architecture (with CPU architecture being a subset of computer architecture).  In practice the details of CPU architecture are typically taught in courses with computer architecture in their title.  More importantly, these two tags tends to be applied somewhat interchangeably and in practice the CPU architecture tag would apply to nearly all of the good questions that have the computer architecture tag.  Also I don't mind if my suggestion is not agreed with, I'm simply stating my reasoning.

Comment: Not all CPUs end up in computers.  Many (most, maybe) end up in embedded systems.  I think the two subjects are different. Whislt there maybe some cross-over of interest, something like a discussion of Chuck Moore's 144-core parallel array CPU architecture doesn't easily fit into computer architecture.